# Does 2002 Ford Escape have a fuel pressure sensor?

Tags: fuel-system, escape

I've watched some videos and on their engines the fuel pressure sensor is at the end of the fuel rail close to the coolant reservoir and AC ports. My engine looks identical but I have no sensor there.

Is it under the air intake manifold? I had it off earlier but I don't remember seeing it there but tbh I wasn't looking.

I searched AutoZone for a fuel pressure sensor for my car and nothing came up.

Does it not have one? V6.

Comment: Could be at the beginning or middle - check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

On that vehicle the fuel pressure sender is located near the fuel tank, see #12 in illustration above. You can use the port on the fuel rail to place a mechanical gauge to verify pressure as a spot check/verification.

Question:  what fuel pressure is displayed on your OBD (OnBoard Diagnostic) readout?

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of fuel pressure sensors. The one shown in the drawing is the fuel tank pressure sensor. The other pressure sensor is located on the fuel rail or close by. Each has a different purpose.
The fuel tank pressure sensor is part of the evaporative emissions control system to detect vacuum or fuel vapor pressure, under 3 psi.
The fuel rail pressure sensor measures secondary fuel pump pressures, around 2000 psi for direct injection systems.
Most fuel rails not using direct injection will have a fuel test port covered by a plastic screw-on cap. A fuel pressure gauge connects to the Schrader valve to measure fuel pressures between 30-70 psi.
Direct injection may have a second fuel pump for higher pressures and a fuel pressure sensor to monitor secondary pressures, sending signals to the ecm.
If your Ford Escape doesn't have direct injection then it won't have a fuel pressure sensor on the fuel rail.

Comment: What drawing is that?

Comment: The one zipzit posted, showing only the fuel tank pressure sensor among other parts related to the tank.

Comment: You should post your own diagram so your answer is complete in and of itself, as other answers can change or even be deleted.

Comment: I referred to drawing and described each sensor location for clarity whether or not drawings are used.